# Timer delay in round proress bar of PYQt5

Tags: timer, pyqt, pyqt5, progress-bar, qtimer

In PYQT5, I want to increase the progress of the round progress bar in UI after every 10 minutes by using PyQt5 for 90 minutes.
I have tried 2 methods 1st by time.sleep() and 2nd by Qtimer.

**1st method "time.sleep"**

```py
import sys
import os
from datetime import time

import qdarkstyle
from ui_main import *
progress_val = 0

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    # APPLY QDARKSTYLE THEME
    self.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyside2())

    # SET PROGRESS BAR VALUE
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setMaximum(420)

    # SET PROGRESS BAR STYLE
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setBarStyle('Donet')

    # SET PROGRESS BAR LINE COLOR
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setLineColor((0, 170, 255))  # ARGUMENT RGB AS A TUPLE

    # CHANGING THE PATH COLOR
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setPathColor((255, 30, 99))

    # SET PROGRESS BAR TEXT COLOR
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setTextColor((233, 30, 99))  # ARGUMENT RGB AS A TUPLE

    # SET PROGRESS BAR STARTING POSITION
    # North, East, West, South
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setInitialPos('West')  # WEST AS STARTING POSITION.

    # SET PROGRESS BAR TEXT TYPE : VALUE OR PERCENTAGE
    # Value, Percentage
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setTextFormat('Percentage')

    # SET PROGRESS BAR FONT
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setTextFont('Arial')

    # TEXT HIDDEN
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_enableText(False)

    # SET PROGRESS BAR LINE WIDTH
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setLineWidth(10)

    # PATH WIDTH
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setPathWidth(15)

    # SET PROGRESS BAR LINE CAP
    # RoundCap, SquareCap
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setLineCap('RoundCap')

    # LINE STYLE
    # DotLine, DashLine
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setLineStyle('DotLine')

    #######################################################################
    ## SHOW ==> MAIN WINDOW
    ########################################################################
    self.show()
    ## == #

    # ANIMATE THE PROGRESS
    # LETS ADD TIMER TO CHANGE PROGRESSES
    # self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    # self.timer.timeout.connect(self.progress)  # progress function
    # self.timer.start(60000)
    #
    # # Change all progresses to zero on start
    # QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setValue(0))

def progress(self):
    global progress_val
    # Set progress values
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setValue(progress_val)

    time.sleep(60)
    # Reset progresses if the maximum value is reached
    if progress_val > 420:
        progress_val = 0;

    # Increase value every 60 ms
    progress_val += 1


########################################################################
## EXECUTE APP
########################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
########################################################################
## END===>
########################################################################
```

**Output:**
In the first method, I used timer.sleep() but the UI got stuck.
**2nd method "QTimer"**

```py
import sys
import os
from datetime import time

import qdarkstyle
from ui_main import *
progress_val = 0


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    # APPLY QDARKSTYLE THEME
    self.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyside2())

    # SET PROGRESS BAR VALUE
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setMaximum(420)

    # SET PROGRESS BAR STYLE
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setBarStyle('Donet')

    # SET PROGRESS BAR LINE COLOR
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setLineColor((0, 170, 255))  # ARGUMENT RGB AS A TUPLE

    # CHANGING THE PATH COLOR
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setPathColor((255, 30, 99))

    # SET PROGRESS BAR TEXT COLOR
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setTextColor((233, 30, 99))  # ARGUMENT RGB AS A TUPLE

    # SET PROGRESS BAR STARTING POSITION
    # North, East, West, South
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setInitialPos('West')  # WEST AS STARTING POSITION.

    # SET PROGRESS BAR TEXT TYPE : VALUE OR PERCENTAGE
    # Value, Percentage
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setTextFormat('Percentage')

    # SET PROGRESS BAR FONT
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setTextFont('Arial')

    # TEXT HIDDEN
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_enableText(False)

    # SET PROGRESS BAR LINE WIDTH
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setLineWidth(10)

    # PATH WIDTH
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setPathWidth(15)

    # SET PROGRESS BAR LINE CAP
    # RoundCap, SquareCap
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setLineCap('RoundCap')

    # LINE STYLE
    # DotLine, DashLine
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setLineStyle('DotLine')

    #######################################################################
    ## SHOW ==> MAIN WINDOW
    ########################################################################
    self.show()
    ## == #

    # ANIMATE THE PROGRESS
    # LETS ADD TIMER TO CHANGE PROGRESSES
    # self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    # self.timer.timeout.connect(self.progress)  # progress function
    # self.timer.start(60000)
    #
    # # Change all progresses to zero on start
    # QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setValue(0))

def progress(self):
    global progress_val
    # Set progress values
    self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setValue(progress_val)

    # time.sleep(60)
    # Reset progresses if the maximum value is reached
    if progress_val > 420:
        progress_val = 0;

    # Increase value every 60 ms
    progress_val += 1


########################################################################
## EXECUTE APP
########################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
########################################################################
## END===>
########################################################################
```

after implementation, the code progress is not made in the expected time. for example, I gave 1 minute means timer.start(6000) but the progress bar takes longer than 1 minute to increase.

**ui_main.py**

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

from PySide2extn.RoundProgressBar import roundProgressBar


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(502, 266)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.progressBarContainer = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBarContainer.setObjectName(u"progressBarContainer")
        self.progressBarContainer.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.progressBarContainer.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.progressBarContainer)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.progressBar = roundProgressBar(self.progressBarContainer)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName(u"progressBar")
        self.progressBar.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 200))
        self.progressBar.setMaximumSize(QSize(200, 200))

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.progressBar, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.progressBarContainer)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
```

Comment: While the first approach is certainly invalid (no blocking should ever happen in UI functions), the second *could* work, but: 1. we don't know how the progress bar was set; 2. you should not use globals; 3. a minute timeout is 60000, not 6000, nor 60. We cannot answer until you show us a valid [mre] of the QTimer approach.

Comment: Btw, I couldn't help noticing that you've *never* accepted an answer to your questions, even when you commented that those answer were useful to you. Be aware that, even if nobody forces you to accept answers, doing so is encouraged (as questions with accepted answers get more visibility) and also polite for the people who spent their time to answer you (and for free), not to mention your gain in reputation (+2 for each accepted answer); on the other hand, people that notice you never accept answers would be discouraged from answering you at all.

Comment: @musicamante I have edited my question kindly review it. and I have noted your suggestion thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea with using the QTimer, But I would just use the timer for it's timed signal emitter, and update the progress bar based on the system clock using `time.time()`.

like this:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.start_time = time.time()
        ...


        self.show()
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.progress)
        self.timer.start(1000)  # this will emit every second 

    def progress():
        if time.time() - self.start_time >= 420:  # this would be 420 seconds
            self.start_time = time.time()
        self.ui.progressBar.rpb_setValue(time.time() - self.start_time)

...
```